# How to inspect a docker container to see if it is going to be removed when it exits?

Tags: docker

is there any way to determine whether or not a container will be removed on exit with a `docker container inspect $id` command? Or any other docker command?

Answer (score 1):

turns out the answer is yes, the particular field is `.HostConfig.AutoRemove`, so for example:

```bash
docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.AutoRemove}}' $id
```

Answer (score 0):

The command provided by @Dave Ankin  will output either `true` or `false`. If it's `true`, the container will be automatically removed on exit. If it's `false`, the container will not be automatically removed.